# How to use cat command in a awk

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, awk

I am trying to replace a text of one file based on the content of other file. For example build.xml have a contents like this:

```
 defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1035
        versionName "1.15.2"
    }
```

where a another file version.text have updated versionCode and versionName

```
versionCode 1044
versionName 1.20.10
```

i want to replace the versionCode and versionName of build.xml file by copy appropriate values from version.text file. so final result of build.xml file should be like this:

```
 defaultConfig {
            versionCode 1044
            versionName "1.20.10"
        }
```

I am doing something like this for changing the versionCode :

```
awk '/versionCode /'cat /opt/scripts/version.text |head -1|tail -c -5'' build.xml > tmp && mv tmp build.xml
```

and for versionName:

```
awk '/versionName /'cat /opt/scripts/version.text |tail -c -7'' build.xml > tmp && mv tmp build.xml
```

but these commands are not working as expected. Can someone give me hint to do this using a single command.

PS: i want to run this in a jenkin pipeline script something like below syntax:

```
sh'''#!/bin/bash -xe
             awk '/versionName /'cat /opt/scripts/version.text |tail -c -7'' build.xml > tmp && mv tmp build.xml

         '''
```

Comment: Please post the expected output too in your post in code tags.

Comment: This should better be asked over at https://unix.stackexchange.com, that's where the `awk` buffs are.

Comment: Why not use `sed` for this?

Comment: @bishop How can you give any hint ?

Comment: @user565, the solution is found, the only thing is that whitespaces before keywords won't be preserved, is that critical?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest well actually i need a same formate because this file then used by the system. Can you please share a solution may be someone can add hint into this.

Comment: I simply would not do it that way.  There are two or three better ways I can think of to solve this problem.

Comment: @Vorsprung i agree there would be more smart way to do this but as i have not much experienced in scripting so this is what i think to do by combining diff commands.

Comment: @user566 you could just have the "first part" of the file in build.xml.1, the middle from your "version.text" and the "end part" as the rest of the file and then cat them together.  Other approaches are using a templating system, a programming language like Perl or Python or an XSLT transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk can handle multiple files, that is, for your requirement, you don't need the `cat` in `awk` codes.

Take a look this example:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$1 in a{$2=a[$1]}7' version.txt build.xml
```

You will see that the values are updated. Sure, it is not exactly what you want, for example, the `versionNumber` value is not wrapped with quotes. You can handle those cases by yourself. I hope the one liner above shows you the way how awk handle two files.

Comment: this won't preserve whitespaces

Comment: Brilliant!...  Yes there is white spaces issues but also it removing the double quotes in versionName value. Is there any way to add double quotes back ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest then don't do `$2=xxx` instead, do `sub(/\S*$/, a[$1])` then the format would be preserved.

Comment: @user565 please read my comment under yours for the whitespaces. Regarding the quotes.. it is the part left to you. it's trivial thing.

Comment: @Kent, doing that is for you to cover the OP requirements